# macOS: rename serial port name

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, serial-port

I am developing a tool for changing the serial port name. If the serial port's name is 'tty.usbserial-name1', how can I rename it to another name, such as 'tty.usbserial-name2' ?

Development environment: Mac, and the development tool is Xcode.

Comment: Why is this question not focused enough? I'm quite experienced and I also wonder what API would allow to rename the device for a serial port. It almost seems as if there is a race to close questions as quickly as possible. And none of the people voting to close it cared to give an explanation.

Comment: I've voted to close this topic because what he or she says is basically "Give me code so that I can publish my app."  That's not a question.  That's a request with zero learning curve.  If he or she said "I have done this much, but the result is not what I had expected.  What have I don wrong?", it would catch curiousity,  and I would find a solution for him or her.

Comment: As an avid SO user, I'm doubtful I could have asked this question better. Besides showing links to un-fruitful google searches to "show the receipts", I'm not sure what more there is to be added. I've found myself in situations like this "Is there an API for _____?", and especially if you don't know the terms or the subsystem involved, it can be hard to search. It's especially bad for a term like "serial port", where "serial" and "port" have overloaded meanings (serial vs. concurrent dispatch queue, a network socket's port)

Comment: Some quick googling tells me this is a question for https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://serverfault.com/